# Removing unnecessary line spaces from source code

Tags: shopify, liquid

When I examine the source code of one of our Shopify stores, I see that there are too many line spaces and I want to remove it.
As far as I know, these spaces belong to liquid codes. Is there a way to remove blank lines?

I've tried Liquid filters but they don't work. Like replace, strip.

https://gyazo.com/dfed59f24dffb1eb79db10508fb294b6

Comment: Please don't include screen shots of code, include the code as formatted text in your question. Secondly why do you want to remove this spacing? What issue is it causing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution. If we change it this way, line spaces do not occur in the source code.

{% include 'data' %}

{%- include 'data' -%}